# Loop through all charts working on one PC and not another

Tags: excel, vba

I was doing a bit of VBA for a work project and ended up going through all charts cause I had to find one in particular, no matter where it might be in the workbook.

I did this code

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
        If cht.Name = "Domain" & s & "_G" Then
            Set chrt = cht
        End If
    Next cht
Next sht
```

It works quite fine on my PC, running Excel 365, but not on my colleague's, who has 2016.
On her PC, it goes through each sheet, but doesn't detect that there are charts on the sheet.

Do you happen to know if it's a known issue and what to do to solve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: That's pretty generic code and it should run fine on pretty much any Excel version.  Something else is going on.

Comment: After `For each sht in ...`, add `Debug.Print sht.ChartObjects.Count`.  On your colleague's system, is it showing `0` for the amount of chart objects in the immediate window? (Press `CTRL+G` in the VBEditor to see the Immediate Window).

Comment: One suggestion is to qualify the workbook/worksheet.  If your colleague has another workbook open the code may be trying to reference the other workbook/worksheet.

Comment: @BruceWayne Did it, on my window it shows the right number, on hers it just shows 0 :(

Comment: @ZackE Closed all other workbooks as an easy test, still not working unfortunately

Comment: Is the code you're using stored in a module of the workbook with the charts? If so, change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went back through the code and it seems it really was the "ChartObjects" that was causing a different behaviour in both PCs.

Here is the code I used instead that worked consistently.

```
       For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            For Each shhp In sht.Shapes
                If shhp.Name = "Domaine" & s & "_G" Then
                    Set shp = shhp
                End If
            Next shhp
        Next sht
```

Comment: That's weird. `ChartObject` has been a thing since VBA was implemented in Excel.